# Why are PROMETHEUS metrics not visible on prometheus endpoint?

Tags: spring, prometheus, spring-bean, micrometer

I am trying to add a few custom gauges to PrometheusMeterRegistry. I can see the metrics (default) on prometheus endpoint when I add the dependency, but I dont see them anymore when i create a bean for the PrometheusMeterRegistry.

I can see the metrics (default and custom) being registered to PrometheusMeterRegistry while debugging but not on endpoint.